# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter MissingMethod Exception is thrown

Tags: json, json.net

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter MissingMethod Exception is thrown

working on Windows Phone 7 application and using JSON.Net files. Trying to create JSON file using JsonText Writer but Missing Method exception is thrown.

This is how we are doing.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter(builder);

JsonWriter writer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter(stringwriter);
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
writer.WriteStartObject();
writer.WritePropertyName("registeruserinfo");
writer.WriteStartObject();
```

Comment: Show the exception details (especially the stack trace) please, it'll help us.

Comment: also put the exception details with your question